# min-height, height, class, id precedence

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a class that receives the same height across the project.  I want one div that is a member of the class to expand dynamically.  So I give the div an ID (more specificity).  I was also under the impression that min-height would take precedence over height (which should allow div expansion).  But the div will not expand when its class has a height set. It works if I remove the height, but shouldn't there be two degrees of more specificity in this case?  Here's the fiddle:

Working:     http://jsfiddle.net/farinasa/WHn9t/

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/farinasa/WHn9t/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="specific" class="lessSpecific">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lessSpecific
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}

#specific
{
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

JS:

```
var box = document.getElementById("specific");
function test() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        box.innerHTML += "Hello<br>";
}

test();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Min-height does not take precedence over height. The ID's rules take precedence over the class' rules. Therefore, add a height: auto to the ID selector and you've nullified the static height for that container.

http://jsfiddle.net/WHn9t/3/

I find it useful to refer to W3Schools to find CSS default values for situations like this where a rule needs to be reset for a specific element. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

```
.lessSpecific
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}

#specific
{
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

or this if you prefer

```
.lessSpecific
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}

#specific.lessSpecific
{
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I would give you a vote, but I'm a bit new still.  I'll come back after I get more rep.